# How can I get session information from koa-session inside a socket.io instance?

Tags: node.js, sockets, session, koa-session

How can I use session information from the module [koa-session](https://github.com/koajs/session) inside a socket.io instance e.g.

In my app.js

```
const sesh = session(app);
require('./sockets/socket')(app);
```

My sockets.js file

```
module.exports = async(session) => {
    let app = require('http').createServer();
    let io = require('socket.io')(app);
    let models = require('../models');
    app.listen(3001);


    // io.use get session information and bind it to the socket

    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        console.log('User Connected');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a session store to `koa-session`, you can use it to access its sessions from their key outside of `koa` request's lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a SocketIO middleware for Koa v2 and SocketIO v2 to handle not only getting of session info from Koa but also saving it back to the session.
Its written in typescript but could be easily changed to vanilla js.
Here is the [Gist](https://gist.github.com/paulrobello/3d701297437422861e956913cbc482c3) of it.